# Make ROS independent from wlan connection with new network inteface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, raspberry-pi, ros

I am starting ROS on Ubuntu 20 on Raspberry PI with setting ROS_HOSTNAME to `$(hostname).local` and ROS_MASTER_URI to `http://$(hostname):11311`.
The problem is that if I am connected to WiFi and then that connection fails (for example if WiFi goes out of range), then the robot stops working correctly.

I was thinking that a possible solution could be to create a new network interface or a VLAN and start ROS on that network and then bridge that new network to wlan interface. This would make the network that the ROS is connected to independent from wlan interface, but it would still have access to network if wlan would be online. I would also like to keep the possibility to connect to robot's ROS through another device on the wlan network.

I am asking here for help because I don't have enough networking knowledge to make this work. So any guidelines would be appreciated. If there is another better approach to solving this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [ros_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) for communication with the robot. It is often used if you have a web interface for your robot and you need to visualize some data from the robot's backend on the web. Or even send a command to the robot.
The counterpart to this node is the `roslibjs` library. You can find it [here](https://github.com/robotwebtools)

For more info, you can check [Robot Web Tools](https://Robot%20Web%20Tools), a collection of tools for web-based robot apps.

However, maybe you are not interested in web apps; you can still use `ros_bridge` with [roslibpy](https://roslibpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is python implementation of rosbridge protocol. It is the same as `roslibjs`, but this uses python instead of javascript.

You can easily create a python app which will use `roslibpy` to subscribe or publish to topics or call services.

This approach is better because you will encapsulate your robotic backend, and you can control what is visible to the outside world with params for the `ros_bridge` node. You can also handle better reconnects if your robot lost wifi connection.

Still, you can use exposed `ROS_MASTER_URI` for rviz and debug proposes, but I wouldn't try to use it for controlling the robot because the connection between nodes won't be recreated if you lose wifi connection.

In my work, we used `ros_bridge` for some time in production AMR, and I have to say that it wasn't as robust as I thought initially. For example, there were issues when the robot changed the wifi access points, and caching messages didn't behave according to the documentation. For the web, we still use it but to control a fleet of mobile robots, we had to abandon it, and we developed our solution based on rabbitmq.

But I guess that if you are using Raspberry Pi, then it is not a production robot, and therefore I think you should be OK with `ros_bridge`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you are saying that we can use rviz through ros_bridge? We would be like to use rviz and rqt_console remotely.
I temporarily solved this problem in a way that the robot connects to localhost by default, but if some debugging is needed, it restarts and connects to hosname.local
The robot actually is intended for production :)

Comment: No, you can't use rviz through ros_bridge. My suggestion was that you can use rviz from another computer, but only your wi-fi is stable. And use ros_bridge for the web or a fleet management app that needs to be created.

Comment: For debugging, you can also use bags. I mean to record a bag from some situation and then play it on your computer. Or you can analyze it with http://wiki.ros.org/Webviz